# Kafka - Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:2181) could not be established. Broker may not be available

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to create my first topic by using the command below:

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:2181 --create --topic test --partitions 3 --replication-factor 1
```

and then I am getting the error below.

```
ost:2181 --create --topic test --partitions 3 --replication-factor 1
[2021-10-07 14:03:15,144] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:2181) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2021-10-07 14:03:15,251] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:2181) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2021-10-07 14:03:15,418] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:2181) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Could you please advise on what exactly is the issue here and how this can be resolved?

[image]

Comment: Voting to close as typo. Zookeeper is not a broker; you're using the wrong port. Read the documentation again, more closely

Answer (score 1):

In the Apache Kafka documentation, under the [Notable changes in 2.2.0](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#gettingStarted:%7E:text=The%20bin/kafka%2Dtopics.sh%20command%20line%20tool%20is%20now%20able%20to%20connect%20directly%20to%20brokers%20with%20%2D%2Dbootstrap%2Dserver%20instead%20of%20zookeeper.%20The%20old%20%2D%2Dzookeeper%20option%20is%20still%20available%20for%20now.%20Please%20read%20KIP%2D377%20for%20more%20information.) states that

> **The `bin/kafka-topics.sh` command line tool is now able to connect directly to brokers with `--bootstrap-server`** instead of zookeeper. The old `--zookeeper` option is still available for now. Please read KIP-377 for more information.

(As of Apache Kafka 3.0.0 `--zookeper` flag was removed).

It's unclear what version of Kafka you are using, but given that it accepted the flag `--bootstrap-server` then you're at least using 2.2.0 (probably < 3.0.0 given the dir name but not important for this question).

If you're using `--bootstrap-server` then you want to be connecting to the port associated to the **Kafka server** not Apache zookeper

Recall that

> The `bin/kafka-topics.sh` command line tool is now able to connect directly to brokers

Therefore, typically port `9092` is used and so your command should be

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --create --topic test --partitions 3 --replication-factor 1
```

---

However, `--zookeeper` is typically used with port `2181` since that's the port that Apache Zookeper tends to run on.